# Alert not working in python selenium

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a script in selenium webdriver and I want to handle an alert, but it's not working.

```
try:
    WebDriverWait("browser", 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +'confirmation popup to appear.')
    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
except TimeoutException:
    print "no alert"
```

I am getting the below error :

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'switch_to'
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Can you show where you're assigning `driver`

Comment: also, why are you passing a string (`"browser"`) to `WebDriverWait` instead of sending the `driver` itself?

Comment: @Omar Thanks, I got it.